# Unable to get hook from context provider

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I am setting up this custom hook with context provider  [based on this approach](https://github.com/jherr/todos-many-ways/tree/master/todo-customhook)

```
const mainState = (initial: number | null = null) => {
  const [edit, setEdit] = React.useState<number | null>(initial)

  return {
    edit,
    clear: () => setEdit(null)
  }
}

const MainContext = React.createContext<ReturnType<typeof mainState> | null>(null)

export const useMainContext = () => React.useContext(MainContext)

export function MainProvider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <MainContext.Provider value={mainState()}>{children}</MainContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Then I am wrapping the whole app in the provider

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDom from 'react-dom'
    
import { MainProvider } from './store'
import { App } from './app'
    
ReactDom.render(
  <MainProvider>
    <App />
  </MainProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

But when I try to get the hook TypeScript errors with

`Property 'edit' does not exist on type '{ edit: number | null; clear: () => void; } | null'`

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { useMainContext } from './store'
    
export const App = () => { 
  const { edit } = useMainContext()
  ...
}
```

Comment: You're getting the type error because your `useMainContext` doesn't have the sneaky `!` from `useTodoContext = () => React.useContext(TodoContext)!`.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that on  the original and thought it was a typo, thanks, what is the meaning of that?

Comment: It's a way to tell Typescript that you know better than him that it cannot be null. In other words: not recommandable.

Comment: @jperl But I tried setting it to `-1` and still had problems

Comment: What did you set to -1?

Comment: I set it to `edit`, if I remove the `!` I still get the error

Comment: Opinions differ as to how to do it. Some for example, do this: `const MainContext = React.createContext<ReturnType<typeof mainState>>({} as ReturnType<typeof mainState>>)`. But that's as bad as adding `! `. Since your context is initialized with null, it has to be treated as such, that it can be null.

Comment: The `!` is the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator).

Comment: @jperl I use mainState as the business logic for the app, edit is just one, but was intending to add more hooks to it

Comment: Btw, there is something wrong going on. What is mainState? A hook? (I suppose, since it uses useState. But do you know how hooks work? You're not supposed to call them outside a component. I don't know where you got that idea. Put the useState in MainProvider.

Comment: Something like this: 

`const [edit, setEdit] = React.useState<number | null>(initial)
return (
    <MainContext.Provider value={{ edit, clear: () => setEdit(null) }}>{children}</MainContext.Provider>
  )
`

Comment: I got the idea from the link on the question, https://github.com/jherr/todos-many-ways/tree/master/todo-customhook, it is meant to avoid drilling the props to many components that may use it

Comment: Or this: `const mainState = useMainState(); return (
    <MainContext.Provider value={mainState}>{children}</MainContext.Provider>
  )` but never ever call a hook outside a component! That's how React keep track of hooks. Note: I renamed mainState to useMainState(). I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Typescript is telling you, the type of your context can either be `null` or `{ edit: number | null; clear: () => void; }`

Remember what you initially set it to: `const MainContext = React.createContext<ReturnType<typeof mainState> | null>(null)`.

You can't destructure null so that's why Typescript isn't happy. Either you don't use destructuring:

```
const context = useMainContext()
context?.edit
```

or you set the context to a different value with a default value for edit.

---

I just noticed that mainState was using useState but mainState seems to be neither a custom react hook nor a component. The react docs states that a custom react hook should start with `use`. And a hook has to be used in either another custom react hook OR a component.

So one way to fix your code:

```
const useMainState = (initial: number | null = null) => { // this is now a custom react hook
  const [edit, setEdit] = React.useState<number | null>(initial)

  return {
    edit,
    clear: () => setEdit(null)
  }
}

export function MainProvider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  // it's called in a component, Ok
  const mainState = useMainState()
  return (
    <MainContext.Provider value={mainState}>{children}</MainContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Now React can keep track of your state. That's why it's also important never to use a hook after a if. The same number of hooks have to be used at all time in a component.

This quite similar to what you did, but you made the call in the prop and even if it worked, it's not that good design-wise.

Comment: Funny I was doing just that, it is a shame I can't use destructure as I really needed it to be `null`